# Showing Lorentz force is always spacelike: Using abstract index notation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation

So the Lorentz force on a massive particle is given by $f^{\mu} = qg^{\mu\alpha}F_{\alpha\beta}\hat{v}^{\beta}$, where $\hat{v}^{\beta}$ is the four vector of the particle and $F_{\alpha\beta} = \partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}-\partial_{\beta}A_{\alpha}$ is the EM field strength tensor, with EM potential $A_{\alpha}$.

I want to show that this force will always be spacelike. And since the four-velocity of a massive particle will always be time-like, then I can prove $f^{\mu}$ is always spacelike if:
$$g_{\mu\nu}\hat{v}^{\mu}f^{\nu}=0$$

I feel like what I am doing is correct, but I am unable to show its zero. I think part of the problem is that I am quite new to abstract index notation, and am unsure how to simplify expressions. Thus far, I have worked out:

$$g_{\mu\nu}\hat{v}^{\mu}f^{\nu} = g_{\mu\nu}\hat{v}^{\mu}qg^{\nu\alpha}F_{\alpha\beta}\hat{v}^{\beta}=q\delta^{\alpha}_{\mu}F_{\alpha\beta}\hat v^{\beta}\hat v^{\mu} $$

Assuming this approach is valid, can anyone hint at where one can go from here? Also, what are some general guidelines or rules for manipulating/simplifying tensor expressions such as these?

Comment: *$\hat{v}^{\beta}$ is the four vector of the particle* You mean the four-*velocity*. Why are you putting a hat on it?

Comment: Contracted Kronecker deltas can be made to disappear.

Comment: The hat just says its been normalized. So $\hat{v}^{\mu} = \frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}$

Comment: Normalized in what way? The right side is the usual definition of four-velocity, not “normalized” four-velocity. Does your book put a hat on it? Which book is it? How does it define the unnormalized four-velocity?

Comment: Its from lecture notes, the unnormalized four velocity of a worldline parameterized by $\lambda$ is given as $v^{\mu} = \frac{dx^{\mu}(\lambda)}{d\lambda}$. And so $$\hat{v}^{\mu} = \frac{v^{\mu}}   {  \sqrt{  -g_{\mu\nu}v^{\mu}v^{\nu} }  }$$ .

Comment: @G.Smith Four-vectors include velocity four-vectors.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Indeed they do.

Comment: @ZacharyC Thanks for the explanation of the hat. What you call the unnormalized velocity vector is what I call the tangent vector, but your notation now makes sense to me.

Comment: @G.Smith Yea sorry about that. Does it even make sense for me to call the tangent vector the "unnormalized 4-velocity"? Or is the 4-velocity defined as always being normalized, as you said?

Comment: @ZacharyC I think your terminology is somewhat unusual. I haven’t encountered it before. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity)’s treatment of four-velocity is the one my textbooks had, where to be worthy of being called “velocity” you have to use the proper time as the worldline parameter.

Comment: What does $f^{\mu}$ being spacelike mean physically?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Does it mean that the force can only act orthogonal to the direction the particle is moving?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder since $||u||^2 = c^2$, always, any 4-acceleration has to be orthogonal to the 4-velocity, and the 4-velocity is time-like.

Comment: @JEB So orthogonality to the time-like 4-velocity implies a space-like acceleration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your last equation, it should be clear that $$g_{\mu\nu} v^\mu f^\nu = q \delta^\alpha_\mu F_{\alpha \beta} v^\beta v^\mu = q F_{\alpha \beta} v^\beta v^\alpha,$$ since only the terms where $\alpha = \mu$ will be non-zero because of the Kronecker delta.

From here it's quite trivial, since $F_{\alpha \beta}$ is an antisymmetric tensor, and $v^\alpha v^\beta$ is a symmetric tensor, and so their contraction is zero. But if you want to show it explicitly:

$$ F_{\alpha \beta} v^\beta v^\alpha =  F_{\alpha \beta} v^\alpha v^\beta = F_{\beta\alpha} v^\beta v^\alpha = - F_{\alpha\beta} v^\beta v^\alpha,$$

where in the first step I've just changed the order of multiplication of $v^\beta$ and $v^\alpha$, in the second step I've flipped the dummy indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and in the third step I've used the fact that $F_{\alpha\beta} = - F_{\beta \alpha}$. From here it should be trivial that it's zero.

Comment: Thank you!! I see why $F_{\alpha\beta}$ is antisymmetric from its definition.  However, can you elaborate on $v^{\alpha}v^{\beta}$ being a symmetric tensor. I never really thought about the two four-vectors alone being a tensor.

Comment: How would you define a rank-2 tensor? :)

Comment: @ZacharyC The (tensor) product of two tensors is a tensor, and vectors are just tensors of rank 1.

Comment: From what I understand, the rank tells how a tensor transforms between basis. So $v^{\alpha}v^{\beta}$ both transfrom contravariantly. So I guess it can be considered a rank (2,0) tensor $V^{\alpha\beta}$? But how do you know that its symmetric in this case and in general

Comment: @ZacharyC Because $v^\alpha v^\beta=v^\beta v^\alpha$. These components are just commuting numbers.

Comment: Well the symmetry isn't too hard to understand, since each individual term of $v^\alpha v^\beta$ is just a product. It shouldn't be too difficult to see that term-by-term, $v^\alpha v^\beta = v^\beta v^\alpha$. As to why it's a tensor, well it transforms like one! :)

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So is this a property of tensor products: $v^{\mu} \otimes u^{\nu} = u^{\nu} \otimes v^{\mu}$.

Comment: @ZacharyC This gets complicated. Tensor products are *not* commutative. But what you wrote is invalid. You can’t put a $\otimes$ between *components* of a tensor. The components of a tensor are not the same as the tensor itself. The components are just numbers that multiply normally and thus do commute. Discussing this further in comments is inappropriate because it could take way too long.